# Help: Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free

Construct the CFG given the following language:

$$\{a^i \; b^j \; c^k \;|\; i = j \; or \; j = k \}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? This is not a homework-answering service. Your question is routine, and you should be able to solve it on your own.

Comment: Hint: Your language is the union of $\{ a^i b^i c^k : i,k \geq 0 \}$ and $\{a^i b^k c^k : i,k \geq 0 \}$.

Comment: You are right I was lazy. I tried on my own and I think I figured it out.

Comment: See below @YuvalFilmus, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be the following:

$$
\begin{align}
&S \to WQ  \mid XY \\
&W \to aW  \mid ε \\
&Q \to bQc \mid ε \\
&X \to aXb \mid ε \\
&Y \to cY  \mid ε
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please, let them do their own homework. You're making life harder for teachers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Set up a grammar to get $i = j$ or $j = k$, then tweak to make sure the equality can't hold.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do the tweaking. If memory serves, this is a canonical example of an inherently ambiguous context-free language.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, you can do it. Write sub-grammars for $a^i b^i c^k$, "fix" the $a^i b^i$ part to ensure equality isn't possible; mirror image gives $a^i b^j c^j$ and different number of $b$ and $c$. The ambiguity isn't an issue here.